# JavaScript promise not firing in order

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I have been trying to effectively manage how I build my promises in my Express.js app.

Right now I have the following scenario: During the signup process, a user has an optional `Organization Name` field. If this is filled in, I need to create the `Organization` object and then add the `_id` of it to the other information that I am applying to the `user`. If there is no `Organization name`, proceed and update the basic `user` info.

<-- Right now the `user` is being updated before the `organization` is being created. -->

```
//basic info passed from the signup form
info['first_name'] = req.body.first_name;
info['last_name'] = req.body.last_name;
info['flags.new_user'] = false;

//if organization name is passed, create object and store _id in user object. 
let create_organization = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  if (req.body.organization_name !== "") { //check if name is sent from form
    Organization.create({
      name: req.body.organization_name
    }, function(err, result) {
      console.log(result);
      if (!err) {
        info['local.organization'] = result._id;
        resolve()
      } else {
        reject()
      }
    })
  } else {
    resolve()
  }
});

let update_user = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  User.update({
    _id: req.user._id
  }, info, function(err, result) {
    if (!err) {
      console.log("Updated User!"); < --prints before Organization is created
      resolve();
    } else {
      reject();
    }
  })
});

create_organization
  .then(function() {
    return update_user;
  })
  .then(function() {
    res.redirect('/dash');
  })
```

Comment: You are not merely defining the Promises, you are already running them. You need a different pattern: `let create_organization = () => new Promise(...);` and `create_organization().then(...)`

Comment: As soon as you create a promise it is executing, make your `update_user` & `create_organization` into functions that return a promise,..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing in your code waits for the first promise to settle before proceeding with starting the subsequent work. The work is started as soon as you call `User.update`, which is done synchronously when you call `new Promise` with that code in the promise executor.

Instead, wait to do that until the previous promise resolves. I'd do it by wrapping those functions in reusable promise-enabled wrappers (`createOrganization` and `updateUser`):

```
// Reusable promise-enabled wrappers
function createOrganization(name) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        Organization.create({name: name}, function(err, result) {
            console.log(result);
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(result);
            }
        });
    });
}

function updateUser(id, info) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        User.update({_id: id}, info, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve();
            }
        })
    });
}
```

*(You may be able to use [`util.promisify`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) or the [`promisify`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promisify) `npm` module to avoid doing that manually.)*

And then:

```
//basic info passed from the signup form
info['first_name'] = req.body.first_name;
info['last_name'] = req.body.last_name;
info['flags.new_user'] = false;

//if organization name is passed, create object and store _id in user object. 
(req.body.organization_name === "" ? Promise.resolve() : createOrganization(req.body.organization_name))
.then(function() {
    return updateUser(req.user._id, info);
})
.catch(function(error) {
    // handle/report error
});
```

*(I stuck to ES5-level syntax since your code seemed to be doing so...)*

Comment: @SamMunroe - Yes, you could do that (although I think that conditional is backward, isn't it? in any case, I never use `==`, `===`, `!=`, or `!==` with booleans).

Answer (score 1):

See, so called 'executor function', passed into Promise constructor, is [**invoked immediately**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Parameters). That's why you essentially have a race condition here between two remote procedure calls. To solve this, make the update responsible for promise creation instead:

```
function updateUser(userId, userInfo) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    User.update({_id: userId}, userInfo, function(err, result) {
      if (err) { 
        reject(err);
      }
      else {
        resolve(result);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

... and call this function in `then()`. By doing this, an executor function will be called only when `updateUser` is invoked - and that'll be after `createOrganization()` finished its job.